# Custom Matplotlib View Window

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got a graph plotted using the `matplotlib` library, and would like to know if there is a way to view from a custom range. I have several vertical lines, starting 0. The beginning of the plot also starts at zero and makes seeing that first line difficult. Is there a way that I can have a view window starting a little more to the left (even though there is no value associated to it)? I know that it was possible in Mathematica with `PlotRange`, but I don't see an equivalent for `matplotlib'.

I've tried playing with the example found on:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/vline_hline_demo.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd

def f(t):
    s1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
    e1 = np.exp(-t)
    return np.absolute((s1 * e1)) + .05

t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
s = f(t)
nse = rnd.normal(0.0, 0.3, t.shape) * s

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
vax = fig.add_subplot(121)
vax.vlines(t, [0], s)

plt.show()
```

but can't the plot to display empty space to the left (or right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plt.xlim` (or `plt.ylim`)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd

```
def f(t):
    s1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
    e1 = np.exp(-t)
    return np.absolute((s1 * e1)) + .05

t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
s = f(t)
nse = rnd.normal(0.0, 0.3, t.shape) * s

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
vax = fig.add_subplot(121)
vax.vlines(t, [0], s)

plt.xlim(-0.2,5.2)

plt.show()
```